# Unwinding to viewController in different Navigation stack not working

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue

[image]

As shown from the diagram, I am trying to have two viewControllers connected to the viewController on the right that serves as a menu between the viewControllers.

When the app is first run, it will load the first view controller on top. A button will show the menu modally and depending on which button is pressed (I am planning to add more) the corresponding viewController will be shown. The FIRST time that VC2 is pressed, it will load the second viewController, but when the menu is called again and VC2 is pressed, I want it to unwind instead of reload the view controller.

I have managed to unwind to the first viewController but when trying to unwind to the second viewController, the action is ignored. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot unwind to a viewcontroller that has not been previously presented, because the desired destination VC will not be held in the navigation controller stack. Unwind segues are designed to 'pop' several steps back in a navigation history. In your scenario, the only possible pop available is to VC1.

You might also want to review your 'menu' concept, considering that UINavigationController objects can provide this behaviour with little fuss. You also don't need two separate UINavigationController objects to achieve what you want.

To do this, simply connect your menu VC as the root view controller for the UINavigationController, then connect the menu buttons to VC1 & VC2. Then you'll be able to move between the three screens with ease (see below for example).

[image]